# D3 Coordinates of mousedover circle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to access the coordinates of a mousedover circle so that a new circle can be drawn and animated in the same position.  Circles are added when the user clicks on the page so are added with this on mouseover property assigned to them.

I'm trying to access the x,y position of the current circle moused over with

```
var y = d3.select(currentCircle).attr("cy");
```

where currentCircle is

```
var currentCircle = this;
```

However, it always gives `null`

currentCircle definitely holds the correct SVG element as when console.log(currentCircle) is called we get

`<circle transform=​"translate(590,358)​" r=​"10" style=​"fill:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​">​</circle>​`

in the console.

How do I get the circle's x and y coords?

Fiddle of the entire setup in the link

http://jsfiddle.net/Tu3EZ/

Comment: You haven't set cx or cy so it really is null. What answer would satisfy you 0 or the transform arguments of 590 and 358. If it's the transform arguments then read the transform attribute.

Comment: Wow I feel stupid now, I thought I'd changed from using a transform to set position of circles to direct cx, cy setting but that was only for the mouseover animation's circle.  All working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Robert's comment:

Turned out I forgot to set the cx and cy for the circles on initialization so these properties were obviously null when being read.

```
.attr("cx", x)
.attr("cy", y)
```

To set initial circle pos rather than

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate("+x+","+y+")"; })
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu3EZ/1/)